# Deploy Node and MongoDB on one VPS or two?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, vps

I'm developing a Node/Express app with MongoDB/Mongoose. I'm new to these technologies so I'm unsure how to deploy.

The easy way is to put everything on the best VPS I can afford, and optimize later when I have real user data. However I want to try make a better decision.

My choices are:

- one VPS for Node/Express and MongoDB
- one VPS for Node/Express, and one VPS for MongoDB

*What should I take into account?* e.g.

- Are there benefits to having MongoDB on a separate VPS?
- Should one have more RAM or CPU, or do they have similar needs?
- Which approach will be easier to scale later?

I assume at a bare minimum, I should have the two VPSs in the same network, e.g. AWS, Azure, DigitalOcean, Heroku. However I see many developers are using MongoLab ("mongo as a service"), which is therefore on a completely separate network (surely this is super slow??).

For anyone who has done this before, can you give me any practical advice, or points I should consider?

Comment: Its all depends on your project traffic and size of the database. Both approach can be scalable later.

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr Yes that is true, and I already stated it in the question, a good answer is "it depends". However, for someone who has experience in this, there are undoubtedly tips for avoiding problems. I haven't done this before so I need some ideas/guidance, things to watch out for, or maybe something I didn't consider because I'm new to this stack.